# Call to undefined method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I want to create a custom function inside my model in order to retrieve data with more compicated queries but I get an error that my method is undefined.

```
//Model
class Host extends Eloquent {
    //custom function
    //or public static function
    public function allWithUser() {
    }
}

//Controller
//or Host::allWithUser();
$hosts = with(new Host)->allWithUser();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some options to access this method, but I think those you shown to us are not right. Those (non static) ways you might be successful:

```
$hosts = (new Host)->allWithUser();
```

and

```
$hosts = new Host;
$hosts->allWithUser();
```

But your static version should have worked.

**EDIT**

If it does not work, you must be instantiating a different version of the Host class.

Change the model class name from ´Host´ to ´HostTest´ and check if

```
$hosts = new Host;
```

Still works for you.

**EDIT 2**

If you find you have two classes using the same name, you can check the file

```
vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php
```

All your autoloaded classes should be listed there.

And if you are on a Linux, you can

```
find /your/app/path | grep Host.php
```

and

```
sudo grep -r "class Host" /your/app/path/*
```

Comment: Edited. Looks like you are using a different version of the Host class.

Comment: Ok my mistake. Thank you for pointing me to the right direction! You are always very helpful. I had forgot I previous version of the class (as you already said) with the same class name but different name file.